# How to convert .SFF file format to .BMP or .PNG or .JPG?

Tags: bmp, file-conversion, file-comparison

I need to convert my SFF file to PDF, then i need verify the document. i.e SFF file and converted file.

For that, I think to convert SFF file to image file and PDF file to image file.
Then comparing the both file using image processing.

To do this method:
Im searching for a program to convert SFF to BMP 
Does anyone know such a program or has another idea how to do the job? 
Thank you in advance...

Comment: http://www.softpedia.com/get/Office-tools/Fax-Telephony/SFFtoBMP.shtml#download

Comment: I have tried this setup already. It is not installing. Just comment prompt window flashes, while double clicking the setup file. Is any workaround need to do? or how to work on this. Please help me.

Comment: Ya Now it is executing, but error as Invalid File Format

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need [reaConvertor](https://www.reaconverter.com/convert/sff_to_bmp.html). It　appears to be a matured tool you can rely on. There is an online version of the tool [here](http://www.imverter.com/)

Comment: i have tried this tool, I am getting error Invalid File.

Comment: @user3485158 the free pack does not have SFF file support. You should go for a premium plan

Answer (score 0):

I think:
https://github.com/Sonderstorch/sfftools

will do what you need (convert sff -> tiff/jpeg/..) and then you can use imageMagic (for example) to go to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly not a current well used image format, however if you have legacy.sff Structured Fax Format, they are similar (not exactly identical) to a Monochrome G4 format.

By far the simplest programmable method to convert is using IrfanView which can Read Modify and Resave as other formats in batches.

Out put can be any other modern image type including Mono.BMP, G4.fax or as PDF (with or without GhostScript)

[image]